# Large file editing and versioning for non-programmers

Tags: git, github, creative-commons

As part of a collaborative Creative Commons project, I would like to allow editors to contribute by editing a relatively large text file: ~8 Mb, ~100k lines. Ideally, contributions would be git pull requests that the project administrator (aka: me) would integrate to the master branch.

However, potential contributors are not programmers, so I cannot assume that they know or are willing to learn how to use git.

Within Github, it is possible to edit text files and to create pull requests from these edits in a way that does not require any proficiency with git. However, [this feature is limited](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-limits-for-viewing-content-and-diffs-in-my-repository#text-limits) to 5 Mb text files.

Basically, I am looking for this Github feature, but not limited to 5 Mb files. I am also interested in wiki-like editors for large text files, as I could generate the git pull requests on the fly from the wiki edits.

Note: this question was duplicated from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498292/large-file-editing-and-versioning-for-non-programmers). I hope superuser is a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to let your collaborators edit files through [GitHub for Window](http://windows.github.com/) or [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/).

You could also try [prose.io](http://prose.io/), but I am not sure if it has file editing restrictions similar to GitHub's.

Answer (score 0):

Split the file up. Editing such a monster *is* painful, whatever tools you use. You could use some tool to splice the pieces together. Without more details on the contents and structure of the file(s), it is hard to give more precise advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing text you might want to try [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

> Gist is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others. All gists are Git repositories, so they are automatically versioned, forkable and usable from Git.

Unfortunately I would assume the size limit would again be a problem here. I have to agree with vonbrand here, dealing with one file that big would be headache.